# Android App not working on Emulator - Cocos2dx following Lynda Tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, emulation, cocos2d-x

There is a lynda tutorial that is called building and monetizing game apps for android and I have been trying to set up the project the way they have. The problem is when I have added the cocos2dx project to eclipse, I cannot run it in the emulator for some reason. This has been an apparent problem online, but I cannot figure out how to solve it. This is what the code looks like:

```
package com.gk.moleitx;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxEditText;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class moleitx extends Cocos2dxActivity{
private Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (detectOpenGLES20()) {
        // get the packageName,it's used to set the resource path
        String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();
        super.setPackageName(packageName);

        // FrameLayout
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams framelayout_params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        framelayout.setLayoutParams(framelayout_params);

        // Cocos2dxEditText layout
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams edittext_layout_params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Cocos2dxEditText edittext = new Cocos2dxEditText(this);
        edittext.setLayoutParams(edittext_layout_params);

        // ...add to FrameLayout
        framelayout.addView(edittext);

        // Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView
        mGLView = new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);

        // ...add to FrameLayout
        framelayout.addView(mGLView);

        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
        mGLView.setTextField(edittext);

        if (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")) {
            mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
        }

        // Set framelayout as the content view
        setContentView(framelayout);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("activity", "don't support gles2.0");
        finish();
    }   
}

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mGLView.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mGLView.onResume();
 }

 private boolean detectOpenGLES20() 
 {
     ActivityManager am =
            (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     ConfigurationInfo info = am.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
     return (info.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000 || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic"));
 }

 static {
     System.loadLibrary("game");
 }
}
```

Then the Android Manifest file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.gk.moleitx"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <activity android:name=".moleitx"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

The project builds correctly and then gives me an error in logcat.

My LogCat error is currently as follows:

```
 12-23 01:50:52.362: D/dalvikvm(355): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gk.moleitx    /lib/libgame.so 0x40514e10
12-23 01:50:52.461: D/dalvikvm(355): Added shared lib /data/data/com.gk.moleitx/lib/libgame.so 0x40514e10
12-23 01:50:52.501: W/apk path(355): /data/app/com.gk.moleitx-1.apk
12-23 01:50:52.571: D/AndroidRuntime(355): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:50:52.571: W/dalvikvm(355): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gk.moleitx/com.gk.moleitx.moleitx}:         java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.checkRenderThreadState(GLSurfaceView.java:1614)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(GLSurfaceView.java:355)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(GLSurfaceView.java:392)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.gk.moleitx.moleitx.onCreate(moleitx.java:79)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-23 01:50:52.591: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  ... 11 more
```

I am using cocos2d-x 2.0.1 and android ndk r8b and android 2.3.3 (10) because the tutorials say to do so. Also I am using windows 7.

My emulator has Use host gpu selected and I can't figure out what the issue is. Any help/insight would be great because I've looked at everything online. I am very new to this so it makes it even harder. Thanks

UPDATE: New Error:

```
12-23 15:03:27.574: D/dalvikvm(593): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gk.moleitx/lib/libgame.so 0x40513408
12-23 15:03:27.773: D/dalvikvm(593): Added shared lib /data/data/com.gk.moleitx/lib/libgame.so 0x40513408
12-23 15:03:27.993: W/apk path(593): /data/app/com.gk.moleitx-2.apk
12-23 15:03:28.465: D/libEGL(593): egl.cfg not found, using default config
12-23 15:03:28.473: D/libEGL(593): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-23 15:03:28.484: W/dalvikvm(593): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 12
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:763)
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
12-23 15:03:28.652: E/AndroidRuntime(593):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

I have no idea what I did exactly but it works in the emulator now! Finally!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. Make sure the API on your Virtual Device is at least what the cocos2dx you downloaded requires. I went ahead and downloaded the newest one (2.2.2) and it requires API 17. If your device doesn't have the minimum API, it will not run. If I'm not mistaken, the one for the Lynda tutorial requires API 10 or higher, but I could be mistaken. Take a look at your Virtual Device and see if it makes a difference. It wouldn't be too difficult to use one that had a higher API to test out and see if it makes a difference. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
mGLView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
mGLView.setTextField(edittext);

if (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")) {
    mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
}
```

`setEGLConfigChooser()` can only be called before `setRenderer()`. Move the `setEGLConfigChooser()` before the `setCocos2dxRenderer()` call.

---

To the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec` problem, make sure your emulator has **GPU emulation** enabled. Or just use a real device instead of emulator.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. But unfortunately that just changes the error to something else (I updated the original post with the new error)

Answer (score 0):

And in `andoridemainfest.xml` change

```
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

to

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```